# Windbg: Figuring out how many times a breakpoint was hit before a crash

Tags: windbg

I set the following breakpoint:

```
bp MSPTLS!LsCreateLine 100
```

The program crashes before the break point is hit 100 times. When I do `bl` after the crash, I get the following:

```
0 e 5dca4b62     0072 (0100)  0:**** MSPTLS!LsCreateLine
```

I am assuming from this information that the break point was hit 72 times before the crash.

However, when I do `bp MSPTLS!LsCreateLine 80` I am able to hit the breakpoint before the crash telling me that the break point was hit more than 72 times before the crash. Does this 72 not indicate how many times the break point was hit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default number format of WinDbg is hexadecimal. If you want decimal numbers, prefix them with `0n`:

```
0:005> bp ntdll!DbgBreakPoint 0n100
0:005> bl
 0 e 7735000c     0064 (0064)  0:**** ntdll!DbgBreakPoint
```

The counter `0064` before `(0064)` counts backwards. You can easily observe that in any GUI application:

```
0:000> bl
 0 e 74fd78d7     000a (000a)  0:**** USER32!NtUserGetMessage+0x15
 1 e 74fd78c2     0064 (0064)  0:**** USER32!NtUserGetMessage
0:000> g
Breakpoint 0 hit
eax=00000001 ebx=00000001 ecx=00000000 edx=00000000 esi=001faf8c edi=74fd787b
eip=74fd78d7 esp=001faf44 ebp=001faf60 iopl=0         nv up ei pl zr na pe nc
cs=0023  ss=002b  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00000246
USER32!NtUserGetMessage+0x15:
74fd78d7 83c404          add     esp,4
0:000> bl
 0 e 74fd78d7     0001 (000a)  0:**** USER32!NtUserGetMessage+0x15
 1 e 74fd78c2     005a (0064)  0:**** USER32!NtUserGetMessage
0:000> ? 5a
Evaluate expression: 90 = 0000005a
```

In the example, breakpoint 0 has been hit 10 times, leaving breakpoint 1 at 90.